# how to layouting the web (HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css, layout

current output:
[image]

desire output:

[image]

I want to make text center.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akffy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhalQ.png)

Comment: We could help you better, if you add tour html and css code to your question.

Comment: oh ya im sorry i forgot to put the code

Comment: Please put the code in question, not in comment. It is not readable here

Comment: i already put the code, im sorry i forgot

Comment: Pasting your code as text would be better than images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). This article might also be helpful: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Investigate CSS flex and CSS grid to help with layouts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
.contentwrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.contentisi {
  text-align: center;
}
```

we do not know your css settings.
use only this.